# Configuring grub-pc. Как с этим бороться? (фото в вопросе)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vds

Взял VDS погонять на тестовом периоде тут: https://proxmox.flynet.pro

Написал скрипт для установки нужного мне ПО: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yarkovaleksei/vds-install-script/master/install.sh

Подключаюсь по SSH к серверу, выполняю команду:

```
root@vpshost:~# curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yarkovaleksei/vds-install-script/master/install.sh | bash
```

Начинается установка и в консоли вылазит вот это (скриншот консоли):
[image]
И трындец... На клавиши консоль не реагирует. Что это и как бороться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно отключить полностью взаимодействие программы *dpkg* с пользователем, установив переменной окружения [DEBIAN_FRONTEND](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch05s03.html.ru#installer-args) значение `noninteractive`.

---

в применении к вашему случаю, можно либо добавить в начале скрипта команду:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

либо предварить каждый вызов программ *dpkg*/*apt** установкой этой переменной. примерно так:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get ...
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt ...
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude ...
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить в скрипт эти строки:

```
echo 'grub-installer/only_debian boolean true' | debconf-set-selections
echo 'grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true' | debconf-set-selections
```

И запускать его внутри `tmux`.